# I want to replace the main exe of a click-once deployed app with another one but the manifest won't let me

Tags: c#, hash, clickonce, manifest

I have created a copy-protection/licence key system for developers (C#) which modifies the main exe of a developers application to add a copy protection loader which runs first when a user launches the app to check their licence key, then launches the actual app when details have been verified with the server.

I want to allow my copy protection app to take the output of a click-once deployment, add the loader and recreate the manifest to reflect the changes to the main exe so that the modified app can be installed as normal with Setup.exe.

I have tried changing the assembly name in the manifest to that of the loader and also amending the size of the exe as stated in the manifest and while this solves the initial errors, the problem now is that the computed hash does not match the new exe and I get the following error:

```
    ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [17/09/2013 11:40:50] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (HashValidation)
    - Application manifest has either a different computed hash than the one specified or no hash specified at all. 
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
    --- Inner Exception ---
    System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (HashValidation)
    - File, SkyCallerPro.exe.manifest, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyFileHash(String filePath, Hash hash)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyFileHash(String filePath, HashCollection hashCollection)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
```

The offending part of the manifest file is this section:

```
    <hash>
    <dsig:Transforms>
      <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
    </dsig:Transforms>
    <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha256" />
    <dsig:DigestValue>JARQfZ0fUMiJDudVERGdBFkgqwLLd/gwnyTkZhMQydQ=</dsig:DigestValue>
    </hash>
```

How can I automatically recompute the manifest file or otherwise bypass this problem?

Comment: Feature, not a bug.  ClickOnce checks that the executable was not tampered with while it traveled from your machine to the user's.  You tampered with it.  You were defeated by your own copy-protection scheme :)

Comment: I need to use click-once! I'll play around with the mage tool and see what I get, I'm sure it's possible

Comment: Thanks for your help guys,  I managed to do it using this : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3tc5xx.aspx][1]


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3tc5xx.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help guys,  I managed to do it using this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3tc5xx.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need to use mage tool to resign the deployment manifest.

This is all well documented in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465299.aspx).